# Installing Cadence , Assura , EXT and MMSIM in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, 18.04

I am new to linux platform, I was using CentOS to work with following applications,

```
Cadence Ver. IC617, 
Assura Ver. 4.15, 
EXT Ver. 15.27 and 
MMSIM Ver. 15.10.257
```

I want to replace CentOS with Ubuntu, Is it possible to install and work with the above mentioned applications (same or higher versions) in Ubuntu?

The existing posts i checked were asked around 7 to 8 years ago, I am wondering if it still works in latest version..